# Apache DirectParquetOutputCommitter vs Netflix S3PartitionedOutputCommitter

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In spark, there is configuration spark.sql.parquet.output.committer.class. It takes the kind of committer we wanted to use while saving the file.

I found these 2 committers pretty commonly used:

```
com.netflix.bdp.s3.S3PartitionedOutputCommitter
org.apache.spark.sql.parquet.DirectParquetOutputCommitter
```

Which one of these is better and what are pros and cons of using each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

com.netflix.bdp.s3.S3PartitionedOutputCommitter usages multi part upload for s3 and write is pretty fast.
I tried org.apache.spark.sql.parquet.DirectParquetOutputCommitter but this is not able to scale for large volume of data.